# Nested echo command in backticks

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, echo, command-substitution

I want to know why an extra echo will print in my shell. I'm using `bash` version 4.2.46(1).

```
echo `echo `echo $SHELL``
```

A interesting issue is if I replace ``` '``' ``` with `$()` it doesn't print extra echo:

```
echo $(echo `echo $SHELL`)
```

And I found that it prints extra echos in odd `echo` command numbers:

`````
echo `echo `echo `echo `echo $SHELL````
`````

Comment: That's what `$()` is for. Backticks don't nest.

Comment: And what backticks do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your two versions:

```
echo `echo `echo $SHELL``
```

and

```
echo $(echo `echo $SHELL`)
```

are not equivalent. The first [backtick command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) ends as soon as another backtick is seen:

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, [...] The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution.

Your first version is actually equivalent to:

```
echo $(echo )echo $SHELL$()
```

which is why you get an "echo" in the output - the command you end up running (after substitutions and with extra whitespace removed) is just:

```
echo echo /bin/bash
```

so the output is "echo /bin/bash", just like if you wrote that command out directly.

---

If you must nest backticks, you can backslash the inner pairs to escape them. Your first command could be written correctly as:

```
echo `echo \`echo $SHELL\``
```

although I wouldn't recommend it — `$( ... )` is made for nesting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, therefore I have to escape inner backticks with `\\`.

Comment: @SepahradSalour NO, the solution is to use `$()`. Why on earth do you want to use backticks when it was already deprecated long ago

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent to

```
echo $(echo `echo $SHELL`)
```

Or, even better:

```
echo $(echo $(echo $SHELL))
```

In backticks will be:

```
$ echo `echo \`echo $SHELL\``
/bin/sh
```

And that is exactly the main problem of backticks:

> ```
>  Where exactly does a backtick start or end?
> ```

That is why the shell does not understand the line correctly.
The shell understand the line to be:

```
echo echo `echo $SHELL`
```